# Vector of objects, using setElementAt/set

Tags: java, object, vector

I tried setting my object2 in vector position 1 with a new object that has been modified by a copy constructor.

```
    Generic object1 = new Generic();
    //invoke the copy constructor of the Generic class

    Generic object2 = new Generic(object1);

    Vector<Generic> myVector = new Vector<Generic>();
    myVector.add(object1);
    myVector.add(object2);
```

this code works when I use it after I inputted data for object1, object2 gets the same data

```
    object2= new Generic(object1);
    myVector.setElementAt(object2, 1);
```

however, I thought the below code should be same as the above, but it does not give me the same data as object1 (just gets the default values of object1)

```
   myVector.setElementAt(new Generic(object1), 1);
```

How come the second one doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the same values as object1" and by "the second one doesn't work"? Assuming that `new Generic(object1)` is a stateless constructor, the two code fragments should be identical (modulo the side effect of assigning a value to `object2`).

Comment: Please supply more code. Is there any implicit casting?

Comment: sorry everyone, added more code

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE, explain what the code of the SSCCE does and what you think it should do instead. Your question as it is isn't very clear to me.

Comment: How are you checking the values of your objects? Which object doesn't have the values that you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ted Hopp wrote in his comment, the two variants are identical except that the second variant does not assign a new value to `object2`.

I think you are not aware of the fact that references in Java are always copied (not the referenced object, but the reference itself): After calling `myVector.add(object2);`, your `object2` and the second element in your vector are independent, apart from referencing the same object.

This means that if you *change the object itself* (e.g. calling `object2.setValue("foo");` this affects both, `object2` and the second element in your vector (as they are referencing to the same object). But if you *set a other/new object as the second element of your vector*, `object2` still points to the old one, so `object2` and the second element in your vector are totally independent.

I hope this helps :-)

---

As a side note: You should probably use `List<Generic> myList = new ArrayList<Generic>();`, unless you need the synchronization `Vector` provides.